# Jmeter run threads sequentially for different loop counts

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have scenario where I have threads like below

```
1thread ---2 loops
 --request1(post)
   --json extractor(id)
2thread ---4loops
 --request2
 --request3
3thread ---2loops
 --request4(deleting that created in 1st thread using id extracted)
```

I have to implement requests as below

```
request1
request2
request3
request2
request3
request2
request3
request2
request3
request4
request1
request2
request3
request2
request3
request2
request3
request2
request3
request4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your design is overcomplicated, my expectation is that you don't need different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as you will have to [pass the `id` between thread groups which is possible](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter), but unnecessary in your case)

Instead of this I would recommend using [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) where you need to make > 1 iteration

Example test plan:

- Thread Group (with 1 thread and 1 loop)

  - Loop Controller (with 2 loops)

    - Request 1

      - JSON Extractor
    - Loop Controller (with 4 loops)

      - Request 2
      - Request 3
    - Request 4

Demo:

[image]

Comment: in this case I have a doubt, is number of threads and loop count are similar? I mean on thread group we have number of threads and loop count, I think both have different functionality, what if want to run request 2 and request 3 for different threads

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to pass the loop count value at the run time to the script by specifying -- *${__P(LoopCount1,2)}* in the loop count field.

Use variable *${__P(LoopCount1,2)}* for first loop, *${__P(LoopCount2,2)}* for second and *${__P(LoopCount3,2)}* for third one and try running the script using non gui mode with the help of command like -

`jmeter -n -t (location of script) -l location for result file -j location for logfile -JThreadGroup=%ThreadGroup% -JRampUpTime=%RampUpTime% -JLoopCount=%LoopCount1% 
-JLoopCount=%LoopCount2% -JLoopCount=%LoopCount3%`